Formation of the matrix that diagonalises a matrix.
Suppose
$$   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$
I calculated the eigenvalues to be 0 and 1, and the eigenspaces have geometric multiplicity 1. Specifically the eigenvectors are $\mathbf{v}_0 = (1,0)$ and $\mathbf{v}_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$.
I am therefore convinced that the matrix can be diagonalised. I have picked $$P = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
   0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  \end{array} } \right],$$ such that $PMP^{-1} = D$.
I have gone through my calculations several times and $$PMP^{-1} = \sqrt{2}   
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
   0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$
It has been a long time since I did my degree, but this should not be the output. At what point am i going wrong?
I have used this site https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/linear-algebra/diagonalize-matrix-calculator/?i=%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%5D%5D
which selects the matrix $P$ to be something different to what I have chosen. Where am I going wrong?
I am sure I remember from class that we need to choose unit vectors for the columns of the matrix of eigenvectors.

If $P=\pmatrix{v_1&v_2}$ is the eigenvector matrix and $D=\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ &\lambda_2}$ is the eigenvalue matrix, then you have
$$
MP=M\pmatrix{v_1&v_2}=\pmatrix{Mv_1&Mv_2}
=\pmatrix{\lambda_1v_1&\lambda_1v_2}=\pmatrix{v_1&v_2}\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ &\lambda_2}
=PD.
$$
Therefore it is $P^{-1}MP$, rather than $PMP^{-1}$, that is equal to $D$.

I am sure I remember from class that we need to choose unit vectors for the columns of the matrix of eigenvectors.

No. If $v$ is an eigenvector, every nonzero scalar multiple of it is also an eigenvector. In your case, you may verify that $P=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 0&1}$ also diagonalises $M$, for instance.

You have$$P^{-1}.M.P=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$So, your matrix $P$ is fine, but you should have computed $P^{-1}.M.P$ instead of $P.M.P^{-1}$.
